# How to apply two filters to a split form to robustly update records in a table

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I am storing data on eye colour, for example. I have a table about  containing 100's of contact details for people in many different local authorities (LA). These contact details change frequently and a team of users will update the table when necessary.

I want to make a split form to do this for us. The idea is to be able to use a drop-down menu for both the LA (location) and the eye colour in the form, to filter the table below to show only the relevant contact details.

The user can then quickly find the correct record, click on it, this will autofill the rest of the form, and any details can be changed and then saved.

My problem is that I can't make the form robust enough to not erroneously overprint existing contact details, and I can't get a two step filter process to work. The contact details for previous records don't seem to clear, even when filtering for different places, so it is easy to muddle up and overprint records.

Here is a screen shot of the form so far:

example of the split form, filtered for records from Broadland but not by colour yet

[image]

Here is the VBA

```
    Option Compare Database

Private Sub Detail_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub LA_AfterUpdate()

Me.Filter = "[LA] = " & Chr(34) & Me.LA & Chr(34)
Me.FilterOn = True

End Sub


Private Sub UpdateRecord_Click()
RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
     Me.Requery
End Sub
```

If anyone could help with:

1. How do I filter for colour as well as place?
2. How can I make the form save the amended record and then clear the form so that no records are overprinted?
3. If I filter for one thing and click to bring up the full record, how can I make the form drop this record and change to a different one if I decide to re-filter and pick a different record

I would be very grateful! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer for question 1**

1.Open form Design View

2.Click at the table at the bottom of your form

3.Open Property Sheet for that table

4.Open Data at Property Sheet. You will see **Link Master Fields** and **Link Child Fields**. Click at **...** sign and it will appear **Subform Field Linker**. Fill in the master and child field's column as you desired (eg. LA, color, place). Then the form will show the result.

**Answer for Question 2**

You have to use vba code under UPDATE RECORD button. For clearing the form after saving the record, use  `DoCmd.OpenForm "your form name",,,,acFormAdd`

**Example answer for question 2:**

```
Private Sub TESTSAVE_Click()    

If MsgBox("Changes have been made to this record." _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to save these changes?" _
    , vbYesNo, "Changes Made") = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord

DoCmd.Close
DoCmd.OpenForm "NewATN2",,,,acFormAdd

    Else
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciate your reply - thank you so much! I will try all this out now (will let you know how it goes).